# Get the cost of SMS after SMS has delivered using Twilio

Tags: php, twilio, twilio-php

I am working on a project where under certain events it will send an SMS message.

What I was planning was when the SMS was delivered, I would keep a record, both for debugging purposes if required, and to keep a history of what's happening with my service. One of the things I was planning on logging was the cost of the message being delivered. It looked like from the Twilio documentation that this is possible, except when I send the message, the response I get back is status `queued` and price is `null`.

I then looked at using the Twilio webhook call back so that I receive an update on the status of the SMS delivery, which also works fine exception I don't get the price I only receive the following:

```
(
    [SmsSid] => redacted
    [SmsStatus] => delivered
    [MessageStatus] => delivered
    [To] => redacted
    [MessageSid] => redacted
    [AccountSid] => redacted
    [From] => redacted
    [ApiVersion] => 2010-04-01
)
```

For reference below is how I am sending the SMS

```
$twilio = new \Twilio\Rest\Client($sid, $token);
            $message = $twilio->messages->create("redacted", array(
                "body" => $smsContent,
                "from" => "redacted",
                "statusCallback" => $callback
            ));
```

How can I get the price of the SMS delivery from Twilio?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've figured a way but it seems a little inefficient as I have to send another request to Twilio to get the full status of the SMS but this is how I've done.

I receive a Twilio request via webhook and I then fetch the message the message using the `SmsId` that is posted like the following:

```
$smssid = $_POST["SmsSid"];
$twilio = new \Twilio\Rest\Client($sid, $token);
$message = $twilio->messages($smssid)->fetch();
$twilioResponse = new TwilioResponse($message);
```

FYI `TwilioResponse` is my own class that has the $message passed in a constructor and I then use it to build and parse my own version for my needs.

Comment: Thank you, I was struggling with this too. I thought about making it as a separate request, but thought that maybe there is a better solution.

Comment: Hi, do you face any issues by doing this? I basically called the message detail API after Twilio sends the webhook with "Delivered" status. Most of the time it gives the price, but is some cases it gives 0. When I look at the console, it says the cost is TBD. It can take a lot of time to generate the cost I assume. So this solution is not so efficient.

Also in case of incoming messages, the price is null and if I delay the call to more than 10 15 seconds, then only the price is included. 

Do you face this as well?

Comment: I never specifically had that issue, but it never went as far as getting real word messages, only in test to my mobile so always worked ok for me

Comment: Is there any way to do this without webhook @Boardy ?

Comment: Not that I am aware of, this method was the only way I found.